# In Dev env of React, app works fine but when I deploy it to Heroku it seems small and css units doesnt seem to work like in Dev env

Tags: css, reactjs, web, heroku, deployment

In Dev all the css works fine and app behaves perfectly, but once I deploy it on Heroku all the CSS seems smaller, the apps works but the design is just diminished smaller. Strange.

Local Env
[image]

Deployed Env [Heroku]
[image]

Comment: Did you maybe resize your browsers zoom? (it goes by URL so it only effects the URL you resized it on.)

Comment: Oh Yes....thats it..spent like weeks on this..Thanks a lot Sir!